# ActiveSheet.QueryTables.add stopped working on mac excel 2016 version 16.9

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Office 2016 on my MAC got upgraded today.
I am now on Excel version 16.9.

Since ever this update the following code gives an error code:

```
ActiveSheet.QueryTables.add(Connection:="URL;http://cabinet.cisco.com:8080/...
Error code: Runtime Error 1004: Application Defined or Object Defined Error
```

Same code works in `Windows` and on the `MAC` using `Office 2011`.

Anyone else having the same problem?
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem since upgrading to 16.9 on Mac

Comment: does anyone have a solution yet? There isn't really a decent developer changelog anywhere ...

Comment: Same issue [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_mac-mso_mac2016/activesheetquerytablesadd-stopped-working-with/9942a0e1-e692-4d8d-8efe-e3c6cf01d35e) and [here](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304933-excel-for-mac/suggestions/33294652-excel-querytable-does-not-work-on-excel-for-mac-in).

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been quietly fixed in the 16.11.0 release!